# How can I omit a class but include all its fields from (un)marshalling in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

The following model:

```
public class SomeType
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private int att1 = 4;

    @XmlElement
    private Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

    public static class Delegate
    {
        @XmlAttribute
        private String att2 = "hi";

        @XmlAttribute
        private String att3 = "howdy";
    }
 }
```

Produces this output:

```
<someType att1="4">
    <delegate att2="hi" att3="howdy"/>
</someType>
```

Is there way to have JAXB omit the `<delegate>` element but include all its attributes (more than one, so `@XmlValue` won't suffice)? Desired output:

```
<someType att1="4" att2="hi" att3="howdy"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if it is possible. But if you don't have to use Delegate in other places and only in this one class you can have below workaround.

Create an intermediate class in desired structure like below which would read fields from original class and you can unmarshal data using this class

**Intermdiate class** : Populate fields in this class by reading fields in original class

```
 public class IntermediateType
    {
        @XmlAttribute
        private int att1 = 4;

        @XmlAttribute
        private String att2 = "hi";

        @XmlAttribute
        private String att3 = "howdy";

        @XmlElement
        private Delegate delegate = new Delegate();    

     }
```

Comment: This won't do, the motivation is to include the Delegate type in several XmlTypes and avoid defining all the common attributes over and over.

Comment: Ok. I get it. Then that is some problem. Voting up the question

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

I don't know, maybe there really is some annotation combination out there or the ability to define some custom adapter/converter, although highly unlikely. JAXB is supposed to enable representation of the xml content as Java objects, so the object graph must match the 'layout' of the xml it represents.

Also, I assume you considered the inheritance, you can just extend your classes from the delegate (you would probably name it then like `BaseSomething` or `AbstractSomething`) and everything would work, but you loose the ability to extend some other class.

**Long answer**

If you can, you should change the xml to the 'undesired' form:

```
<someType att1="4">
    <delegate att2="hi" att3="howdy"/>
</someType>
```

Think of the other side which is consuming this xml (or producing it if/when you are the consumer). They would probably appreciate the ability not to repeat themselves as well. All JAXB-like frameworks work in a similar fashion, even in languages other than Java.

However, if you cannot change the actual xml form and would like to use better encapsulation in your code when working with these objects, you could implement `SomeType` using an approach similar to this:

```
public class SomeType {
    @XmlAttribute
    private int att1 = 4;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String att2 = "hi";

    @XmlAttribute
    private String att3 = "howdy";

    public void setDelegate(Delegate delegate) {
        this.att2 = delegate.att2;
        this.att3 = delegate.att3;
    }

    public Delegate getDelegate() {
        return new Delegate(att2, att3);
    }

    public static class Delegate {
        private String att2 = "hi";

        private String att3 = "howdy";

        public Delegate(String att2, String att3) {
            this.att2 = att2;
            this.att3 = att3;
        }
    }
 }
```

My point is if you need to accommodate to not-so-well structured xml, then I'm afraid that you will not be able to escape copy-pasting JAXB-annotated code. Defining an xsd schema and generating the classes from it can sometimes make this a less tedious job.